# How do i parse data in React Native from a url?

Tags: javascript, react-native, logic

I don't mean call API , so it would not be `fetch()` or `WebView`. That would be like Jsoup in Java .

Is any ways to complete it in React Native ? I try to find the answer but can't find it , someone can tell me or show me the link , that would be appreciated . Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

i am working at same issues and i found solution here's my steps

1. npm install Buffer, eslint, events, stream, url, util
2. install [this](https://github.com/tradle/react-native-http) with zip (not with npm)  and extract to your node_modules
3. you must to edit your some files here it is

App\node_modules\react-native-http-master\lib\request.js

Delete  "`var Base64 = require('Base64');`" and "`this.setHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ' + Base64.btoa(params.auth));`"

App\node_modules\react-native-http-master\lib\response.js

Add   "`var Buffer=require('Buffer');`" to first line and change this line  "`this.emit('data', new Buffer(respBody.slice(this.offset)));`" to "`this.emit('data', Buffer(respBody.slice(this.offset)));`"

react-native code look like:

```
var http = require('react-native-http-master');


http.get({  host: 'www.google.com',path : '/' }, (res)=> {
  var data = '';

  res.on('data', function (buf) {
      data += buf
  })

  res.on('end', () =>{
      this.setState({  yourStateVariable: data });
  })
```

[Fast HTML Parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fast-html-parser)

```
var HTMLParser = require('fast-html-parser');
var data=HTMLParser.parse(this.state.yourStateVariable);
```